# How to create month/year filters in Excel, while using jExcel?

Tags: excel, jexcelapi

In Excel, if we had a date column, and we add the filter at the top of the column, we would see filters by year, month etc.  For example, if we had a column with two values like this "03/11/2014" and "02/11/2014", we would see a filter for 2014 and for March and February (as long as the column is formatted as a date column).

I'm writing into excel with jExcel.  I format a column as a date column, like this:

```
        WritableCellFormat cellDateFormat = 
    new WritableCellFormat(new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 12), 
DateFormats.FORMAT9);
```

When I open the excel file, the column shows up as a date column.  However, when sort is added to the column, it doesn't show month or year filters.  Any idea how to fix this?